# How can I plot a grouped barplot in ggplot based on frequency?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to plot a grouped barplot with the values `avg_r` and `price_l` , but based on the frequency of `price_l`.
I tried something like this:

```
g1 <- ggplot(sub.dt, aes(fill=price_l, y=seq(0,24,1), x=avg_r)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")

g1
```

Which gives me that:

[image]

So, for example 2.5 should be at 1 at the y axis.
Here is some code for reproduction:

```
price_l <- c('€€-€€€', '€€-€€€', '€€€€', '€€-€€€', '€€-€€€', 
             '€€-€€€', '€€€€', '€€-€€€', '€€€€', '€€-€€€', 
             '€€-€€€', '€€-€€€', '€€-€€€', '€€-€€€', 
             '€€-€€€', '€€-€€€', '€€-€€€', '€€-€€€', '€€€€','€', '€', 
             '€', '€','€€€€', '€')

avg_r <- c('4.5', '3.5', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0', '3.5', '4.5', '4.0', '3.0', '4.0', 
           '3.0', '5.0', '4.5', '4.0', '3.0',
           '3.5', '4.5', '3.5', '3.5', '4.0', '3.0', '4.0', '4.0', '2.5', '4.5')
             
sub.dt <- data.table(price_l, avg_r)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stat = "count"`:

```r
ggplot(sub.dt, aes(fill=price_l, x=avg_r)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="count")
```